# How to evict cache in multiple pods? I have two Openshift pods and I want to send a HTTP request for evict cache in both pods

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, spring-cache

I have two microservices pods in Openshift, I want to clean cache both microservices. I have a endpoint that clear-evict cache, the request only enter in one pod. How to avoid restart the pods for clear-cache? I use 2.1.10 springboot and I have a cron configurated every two hours but I want to clean cache in HTTP Request.

I use @Cacheable from org.springframework.cache.annotation in the request and org.springframework.cache.CacheManager.clear for evict/clean the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like other services in the Spring Framework, the caching service is an abstraction, not an implementation and requires the use of an implementation to store the cache data. This abstraction is materialized by the org.springframework.cache.Cache and org.springframework.cache.CacheManager interfaces.

You have not spoken about which is your Spring cache implementation, so I suppose that you are using the default implementation.

By default, Spring chooses java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap. This implementation stores your data in-memory and will disappear it when you will close your JVM. For your concrete enviroment, with multiples pods, you need a **cluster-aware cache implementation**. You can't rely on cache implementations based on in-memory storage.

So, you should check out implementations like Spring Redis Cache, which is a cluster-aware cache implementation, and configure it in all your pods.

Comment: I want to sent a HTTP request to all pods running... How I do it with springboot?

Comment: Why do you prefer doing a HTTP request over choising Spring Redis Cache as cache implementation? Sorry, but really you do not want to send a HTTP request. Just you are thinking that a HTTP request will solve your question. Read about the famous XY problem first. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Other mistake in your initial question: you are speaking about a cron in order to clean the cache managed by CacheManager. Some cache implementations have a concept called "expiration". The default implementation in Spring, ConcurrentMap, does not support it, but others like Caffeine (in-memory) or Redis Cache (cluster-aware) do support it. So, if you change now your implementation, you will be able to configure the expiration attribute and get rid your cron

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend 2 options.

1. Instead of sending HTTP request, make the service speak to a kafka topic. Each pods should belong to a different consumer group. Send a kafka message to evict cache on both the consumers.
2. Make the pods speak to a redis db. If one pod receives the request to evict cache then update the redis database with some sort of timestamp. The other pod which frequently checks the redis db will also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sathesh's proposal, I would recommend using hazelcast:

https://docs.hazelcast.com/tutorials/kubernetes

hazelcast can work with a centralized server ("Client/server"), or in a distributed way with no central server ("Embedded") where each participant held an embedded "server" and all the pods of a service are "auto discovered" to talk to each other

https://docs.hazelcast.com/tutorials/kubernetes-sidecar

HZ embedded server with spring-boot:
https://docs.hazelcast.com/tutorials/caching-springboot-jcache#configure-for-embedded